# ClassNotFound exception when using admob jar in my android project?

Tags: android, admob, classnotfoundexception

i have added google admob jar, have added jar file to builtpath and also have declared both the adactivity to enifest file as described in http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android link.. then too i am getting following error..

I am using android 2.3 simulator and using ADT17 latest one.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out r17 of Android Tools requires the /lib folder to be /libs, and the SDK has to be placed in there and referenced internally in order for it to be included in the apk.

check this question for more information
[ClassNotFound when trying to implement AdMob banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815505/classnotfound-when-trying-to-implement-admob-banner)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a problem with ADT 17. Here's a [nice link](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17) for solving this problem.