# Class Not found error after adding admob in android

Tags: android, xml, admob

I have added admob to my xml layout but im getting error like "class not found" i have checked my manifest file and my xml code many times  but i dont know how to resolve it..!! Plz help!! Thanx in advance

```
   The following classes could not be instantiated:
```

This is my error in xml

```
    - com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
      See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(                                                com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:352)
at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:125)
```

My part of manifest file

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
          <activity 
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                                      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
         ></activity>
```

My xml where i have added admob code`enter code here`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/secondpages1"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/firebutton"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    android:background="@drawable/firebutton" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adids"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="My id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check the answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815505/classnotfound-when-trying-to-implement-admob-banner)

Comment: which admob lib do you use?

Comment: GoogleAdMobAdsSdk 6.4.1 @donfuxx

Comment: I checked the link I have added perfectly to libs folder @Lal

Comment: ok, that is the old admob sdk, so your code looks correct. Is "Order & Export" checked?

Comment: No What iam supposed to do? @donfuxx

Comment: Have ordered and exported the jar too !!Still doesnt work @donfuxx

Comment: have you imported it as an external jar?

Comment: Yea I had already exported but stil I couldn't resolve it@donfuxx

Comment: @anusha  I don't import the library myself. Just copy/paste in the libs folder in my project and it works fine. Can you try reversing everything you have done with the library till now and just copy/paste it?

Comment: Am I supposed to copy and paste in my eclipse or workspace. ? Because if I add in my workspace its not getting added in my eclipse. .so should I paste in eclipse alone?@kunalxigxag